# SMTP relay - send email from console application

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtp

Is it possible to send email from a server that uses smtp-relay through a .net application.

I'm using app.config to get the actual values ex server IP, and the fromadress that the email should use.

According to the IT-technician the username and password to authorize should not be needed because it uses smtp-relay. The computer that are going to send the email is on the smtp-servers list of valid computers.

Can this actually work, don't I need to specify the username/pwd?

```
try
{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient(_smtpserver);
    mail.From = new MailAddress(_fromAdress);
    mail.To.Add(_toAdress);
    mail.Subject = _subject;
    mail.Body = _body;
    mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
    SmtpServer.Port = Convert.ToInt32(_port);
    SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(_authUsername, _authPassword);
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
    SmtpServer.Send(mail);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: To expand on @Lloyd's point, you should try it. If it fails, come back and ask a question about the specific failure if you're stuck.

Comment: Yeh sometimes it's a lot easier to just try these things than ask here. You'll usually find out quicker :)

Comment: You are more likely to get assistance if you accept answers from your old questions.

Comment: The code works when I use it on my gmail account but fails when I try to use a relayserver inside our network. The computer that executes the application is added to the relayserver list of authenticated computers.

Answer (score 3):

In your snippet you are specifying credentials

```
SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(_authUsername, _authPassword);
```

You can remove that line and it still will work if SMTP relay is configured as you said.

Answer (score 0):

in your case,if you are seting your username  and password in webconfig even then you need to call it like above.
but if you using your default mail credentials then it will pick automatically..
and if you are using diiferent mail client for sender then you have to pass credentials..

Answer (score 0):

I had same situation. I got same error code. I noticed , I had used system.web.mail. But my application is a console application. I changed library, I used system.net.mail. And it works now.